# Singleton in Objective C (Non-ARC)

Tags: objective-c, singleton

I have found how to implement singleton in objective c (Non-ARC).

[Matt Galloway's singleton](http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/)

```
// AppTools.h in my code

@interface AppTools : NSObject {

    NSString *className;
}

@property ( nonatomic, retain ) NSString *className;

+ ( id ) sharedInstance;

@end    // AppTools


// AppTools.m in my code

static AppTools *sharedAppToolsInstance = nil;

@implementation AppTools

@synthesize className;

- ( id ) init {

    self = [ super init ];
    if ( self ) {
        className = [ [ NSString alloc ] initWithString: @"AppTools" ];
    }
    return self;
}   // init

- ( void ) dealloc {

   // Should never be called, but just here for clarity really.
   [ className release ];
   [ super dealloc ];
}   // dealloc

+ ( id ) sharedInstance {

    @synchronized( self ) {
    if ( sharedAppToolsInstance == nil )
        sharedAppToolsInstance = [ [ super allocWithZone: NULL ] init ];
    }
    return sharedAppToolsInstance;
}   // sharedInstance

+ ( id ) allocWithZone: ( NSZone * )zone {

    return [ [ self sharedInstance ] retain ];
}   // allocWithZone:

- ( id ) copyWithZone: ( NSZone * )zone {

    return self;
}   // copyWithZone:

- ( id ) retain {

    return self;
}   // retain

- ( unsigned int ) retainCount {

    return UINT_MAX;    // denotes an object that cannot be released
}   // retainCount

- ( oneway void ) release {

    // never release
}   // release

- ( id ) autorelease {

    return self;
}   // autorelease
```

I'd like to know how to work allocWithZone: in sharedInstance method.
On this, the allocWithZone: method's receiver is 'super' and 'super' is NSObject.
Though return value is NSObject instance, it is substituted to sharedInstance.

Where is className's memory room then?
I don't know how to work this part of the code.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask "Where is className's memory room then?"

Most classes do not implement `alloc` or `allocWithZone` themselves but rely on the implementation inherited from `NSObject`. The `NSObject` implementation allocates an object of the *original calling class*.

So in your example `AppTools` does override `allocWithZone`, this implementation invokes `NSObject`'s `allocWithZone` via a call to `super`, and `NSObject`'s method performs the actual allocation and returns an object of type `AppTools`.

*[Note: If you are wondering how `NSObject`'s implementation knows what kind of object to allocate then this is simple - calling an inherited method does not alter the `self` argument to the method, `alloc`/`allocWithZone` are class methods, and the `self` argument of a class method references the class object (rather than an instance object of the class) itself.]*

Comment: I've been confused on how to work super keyword. I must have been out of my mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think that code that you have posted is too difficult to use for creating singletons.

In all my project I am using the following code to use singletons. It is very simple, thread-safe and works perfectly:

```
+ (CustomClass *)shared
{
    static CustomClass *singleton = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        singleton = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
    });
    return singleton;
}
```

And I believe you could use it in ARC and non-ARC projects.

**UPDATE:**
As mentioned in comments it is actually `shared object` and not `singleton` because there could be created more the one instance of particular class. But it is close enough.

In my opinion, if you are not writing open source code/libraries and nobody else will use it then it might be much easier to use shared objects and treat them as singletons.

Comment: but it is not a singleton — while close enough, IMO

Comment: @vikingosegundo why it is not?

Comment: a singleton is a class that can be only instantiated once. you have an class, that offers an shared object. But there is nothing stopping the user to create another object.

Comment: and actually that is a good thing. Singletons can be hell, ie in unit tests.

Comment: Just to add my support, there is no point in trying to create some clever bit of singlton code, Apple doesn't bother, you see +[WhatEver sharedWhatEver] all over the place. Focus you efforts on creating well designed code that solves real issues. I see this problem a lot with programmers who take pride in the wrong things, refusing to use ACR or interface build, coming up with lame arguments about better performance which they haven't shown is significant, real or required. The job of a programmer is to create the most maintainable bug free code they can, not show how clever they can be.

Comment: I dont want to show you, how smart I am, or clever. I just hinte, that this is not a singleton, while it is good enough. If a question asks for a singleton, and you offer the sharedObject approach, you should at least mention, that you cant use it as you would do with an real singleton. A real singelton would allow me to create new objects, but I get only the same back. With this approach, you must tell the user to use always the shardObject object, otherwise the user might think, he can access the same object through init — and this will lead to problems.

Comment: Again: this is not a sigleton, but it is good enough and probably what the user wants. But the user must know, that it works differently than a  traditional singleton.

Comment: Actually, it is a singleton.  That it can be separately instantiated does not change that and there are a handful of Apple provided classes that do the same (NSFileManager comes to mind).

Comment: I would go with [this definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern): "A singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object." It is a sharedObject. That is close enough, but must be treated a bit different.

Comment: @bbum - vikingosengundo is correct, the code in this answer doesn't make a *singleton*.

Comment: Sorry vikingosegundo, I wasn't referring to you, I was just trying to add support to the keep it simple approach.

Comment: @vikingosegundo guys thanks for you comments. Added your and my thoughts to the answer so hope it will be clear for everyone

Comment: @vikingosegundo is correct in terms of CS, but not in terms of the Apple frameworks.   NSFileManager, for example, is documented as a class that is a singleton, yet it also supports individual instances.  NSCalendar is similar, but supports multiple singleton instances (each with different configurations).  NSBundle also maintains a singleton instance per framework/bundle.  That Objective-C & the Apple frameworks diverge from the strict definition should be no surprise in that the language often uses configured instantiations instead of deep hierarchy subclassing like other OO languages.

Comment: @bbum Actually NSFileManager WAS a Singleton (in CS terms): «The NSFileManger used to be a "strict" implementation of the Singleton pattern prior Mac OS X 10.5 and in iOS 2.0. […] Now creating new instances is recommended for thread-safty.» — Objective-C Design Patterns for iOS, pp 104.  
Apple uses the same [definition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html), just to lie about NSFileManager and others in the very next chapter.

Comment: Yes -- I'm quite familiar with the history of it all and that the word "singleton" is used regularly to describe said classes both in the source of said classes and when discussing implementation details with the authors.

Comment: @bbum I am quite sure, that you are familiar with it. I just added your name, so that you got informed of a new comment.

Answer (score 2):

I use the same code as Nekto but `singleton = [[CustomClass alloc] init];` should be `singleton = [[self alloc] init];`.

Imagine a subclass `CustomSubclass`. If you call

```
CustomSubclass *sharedObject = [CustomSubclass shared];
```

you will not get a `CustomSubclass` but a `CustomClass`.